# How to stop LinkedIn from using wrong page title in message previews

Tags: wordpress, share-open-graph

I have a client who has just launched her small business. I'm not sure who set-up her Wordpress website, but I was brought in to finish it. She is trying to promote herself on LinkedIn, but when she sends the URL to a prospect, the link preview says "I'm an e-Learning Developer". The problem is, she isn't an e-Learning Developer. She's a Virtual Assistant. The phrase "I'm an e-Learning Developer" doesn't appear ***anywhere*** in the source code. I've configured all the metadata, flushed the Wordpress cache, and flushed LinkedIn's cache using the Post Inspector tool, but it still comes up with "I'm an e-Learning Developer" when the URL of her website is shared in a LinkedIn message.

The site is running Wordpress with the Divi templating tool. I haven't found anything in Divi's settings that could be causing this. There were no other plugins installed. I've installed AIOSEO in an attempt to fix the problem, but it hasn't helped.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Open graph tags , these tags enables any web page to become a rich object in a social graph.

you can find more information about Open graph tags [here](https://ogp.me/)

There are some WordPress plugins which makes it easy to setup these tags like "All in One SEO" plugin for example, you can setup these information by clicking on edit on the page you want to, then go down to AIOSEO Settings section -> social tab.
Or you can setup these info globally from inside All in One SEO settings.
Watch the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9awNfmLA5RQ).

Comment: I've done that already, but it's still pulling this erroneous description from thin air.